# Switching slack status automatically when connecting to specific wifi networks? (MacOs)

Tags: macos, automation, launchd, macos-ventura

I found [these instructions](https://www.schiff.io/blog/2017/08/31/automating-slack-status-launchd) for automating Slack status based on the connected wi-fi. The post is quite old and it is not working for me on MacOS Ventura.

To be honest, I don't even know how to debug such a script.

Could somebody help?

(alternatively, is there a better solution? some tool to automate processes based on events?)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a third party software called EventScripts.